# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lcom/gu/option/Option;

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I am a newbie Android Developer, this is the 1st time I ask question on Stack Overflow, please give me some advices if anything I can do better.

I wrote my 1st app with Android Studio and I could publish the old version (targetSdkVersion 28) on Google Play without any serious problem.

Recently, I made some update in my app, and it passed the all the test in virtual devices in my computer.
However, after I uploaded it to Google Play, it showed the following error .

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-2
Process: com.gashho.tms_sparscoringsystem, PID: 21482
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lcom/gu/option/Option;
at net.rdrei.android.dirchooser.DirectoryChooserFragment.<init>(DirectoryChooserFragment.java:61)
at net.rdrei.android.dirchooser.DirectoryChooserFragment.newInstance(DirectoryChooserFragment.java:91)
at net.rdrei.android.dirchooser.DirectoryChooserActivity.onCreate(DirectoryChooserActivity.java:38)
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7144)
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7135)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1271)
at androidx.test.runner.MonitoringInstrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(MonitoringInstrumentation.java:2)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2931)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3086)
at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:78)
at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108)
at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1816)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
at androidx.test.espresso.base.Interrogator.loopAndInterrogate(Interrogator.java:10)
at androidx.test.espresso.base.UiControllerImpl.loopUntil(UiControllerImpl.java:7)
at androidx.test.espresso.base.UiControllerImpl.loopUntil(UiControllerImpl.java:1)
at androidx.test.espresso.base.UiControllerImpl.injectMotionEvent(UiControllerImpl.java:6)
at androidx.test.espresso.action.MotionEvents.sendUp(MotionEvents.java:6)
at androidx.test.espresso.action.MotionEvents.sendUp(MotionEvents.java:1)
at androidx.test.espresso.action.Tap.sendSingleTap(Tap.java:5)
at androidx.test.espresso.action.Tap.-$$Nest$smsendSingleTap(Unknown Source:0)
at androidx.test.espresso.action.Tap$1.sendTap(Tap.java:1)
at androidx.test.espresso.action.GeneralClickAction.perform(GeneralClickAction.java:4)
at androidx.test.espresso.ViewInteraction$SingleExecutionViewAction.perform(ViewInteraction.java:2)
at androidx.test.espresso.ViewInteraction.doPerform(ViewInteraction.java:19)
at androidx.test.espresso.ViewInteraction.-$$Nest$mdoPerform(Unknown Source:0)
at androidx.test.espresso.ViewInteraction$1.call(ViewInteraction.java:2)
at androidx.test.espresso.ViewInteraction$1.call(ViewInteraction.java:1)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6718)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.gu.option.Option" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/system/framework/android.test.runner.jar", zip file "/system/framework/org.apache.http.legacy.boot.jar", zip file "/system/framework/android.test.mock.jar", zip file "/data/app/androidx.test.tools.crawler-AfAAed1WQFIsjeH0O51bcw==/base.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.gashho.tms_sparscoringsystem-BozE5VukZcpK-sLBaG0_iw==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/androidx.test.tools.crawler-AfAAed1WQFIsjeH0O51bcw==/lib/arm64, /data/app/com.gashho.tms_sparscoringsystem-BozE5VukZcpK-sLBaG0_iw==/lib/arm64, /system/lib64]]
at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:134)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:379)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
... 37 more
```

Based on the solution from others, I once settled the same problem by adding the followings on dependencies:

```
implementation 'com.gu:option:1.3'
implementation 'net.rdrei.android.dirchooser:library:3.2@aar'
```

and below on allprojects repositories:

```
maven { url 'http://guardian.github.com/maven/repo-releases' }
```

However, after the recent update and make the targetSdkVersion to 29 as requested by Google Play. The same problem come out again.

Here are my gradle files.
gradle(App)

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
android {
compileSdkVersion 29
buildToolsVersion '30.0.2'
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.gashho.tms_sparscoringsystem"
    minSdkVersion 16
    targetSdkVersion 29
    versionCode 7
    versionName "1.1"
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}

buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}
dependencies {
implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
implementation files('libs/jxl.jar')
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:2.0.4'
implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.gu:option:1.3'
implementation 'net.rdrei.android.dirchooser:library:3.2@aar'
}
```

gradle

```
buildscript {
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    google()

}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.2.1'
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.10'
}
}
allprojects {
repositories {
    maven { url "https://maven.google.com" }
    maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
    maven { url 'http://guardian.github.com/maven/repo-releases' }
    mavenCentral()
    google()

}
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Please advise if I need to provide further information. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Looks like latest release is [3.0](https://github.com/passy/Android-DirectoryChooser/releases/tag/v3.0), not 3.2 (might be a broken unfinished version).

Comment: but it shows [3.2](https://github.com/passy/Android-DirectoryChooser) on the usage page

Comment: "build failing" for that version. If you go the releases page, the latest release is 3.0.